# How to reference parent model from Carrierwave Uploader object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, carrierwave

I want to run some methods after the upload of a file has been completed via Carrierwave. Carrierwave includes several callback methods detailed [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-use-callbacks).

I'm planning on using the :store callback.

That's great, but it requires me to run the callback method in the Uploader object instance. This isn't the end of the world, but I want to keep all the logic inside of my parent Model.

**My question is: How should I be referencing the parent model from the Uploader? I don't see anything obvious in the documentation?**

I suppose I could do something like

```
ParentModel.last.call_my_method_here
```

but this seems like a very brittle way to code this (not expecting a lot of requests, but still).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess the `model` variable is what you were looking for, see examples using it [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#conditional-versions)

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I have used the `after_commit` callback on parent model which so far seems to be working properly. This is allowing me to interact with the uploaded file as well.

Comment: Would you please give some example? I have tried your suggestion but it did not work.