# Can't Access foreign key belongs to on carrierwave uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-5

I have Foo and Bar model

- Foo `belongs_to` Bar
- Bar `has_one` Foo

I want to get `bar_id` on carrierwave uploader but it value always nil. I have debug on initialize

```
class FooUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  def initialize(*)
    super
    binding.pry # debug here
  end

end
```

Pry screen when debug :

```
[1] pry(#<FooUploader>)> model
=> #<Foo _id: 585347a5fe37a81f4773b3ac, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, picture_filename: nil, bar_id: nil, name: "test", slug: "test", description: "test">
```

I'm sure `bar_id` value is exist, I have try two way :

put in controller

```
def create
  bar = Bar.first
  @foo = Foo.new(foo_params.merge(bar: bar))
end
```

or put in form

```
<%= f.hidden_field :bar_id, value: Bar.first %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access every attribute from the model the uploader belongs to with the `model` attribute.

References:

- [How to reference parent model from Carrierwave Uploader object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060784/how-to-reference-parent-model-from-carrierwave-uploader-object)
- https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#conditional-versions

So in your case

```
class FooUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  def initialize(*)
    super
    puts model.bar_id # Or model.bar for the model
  end

end
```

Comment: I think you didn't cleary read my problem, I have try debug on initialize but `model.bar_id` always nil.

Comment: Oops Sorry. I read that you just tried to call `bar_id` instead of `model.bar_id`. Have you tried to access `bar_id` when you save `Foo`?. Is it still nil then? Also you could try to set `bar_id` on `new` instead of `bar`: `foo_params.merge(bar_id: bar.id)`

Comment: `bar_id` is not nil when save a `Foo` record.